# Gunicorn flask app can't download file using playwright on linux

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, playwright

I'm making a ReST API using Flask and Playwright to download some files on a server.  Locally, it works but, in server (Linux), returns a permission error.

```
file = await self._loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: open(path, "wb"))
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/apis/tceprotocolo/infos-(19).html'
```

```py
local_save = '/var/apis/tceprotocolo'
def atualiza_json_consultas():
    campos = ['Situação', 'Número', 'Órgão', 'Convenente', 'CPF/CNPJ Convenente', 'Objeto', 'Ínicio', 'Fim', 'Valor Concedente', 'Val']  
    anoa = int(datetime.datetime.now().date().strftime("%Y")) - 4
    try:
        with sync_playwright() as p:
            nav = p.chromium.launch()
            for ano in range(anoa, anoa+5):
                page = nav.new_page()
                temp_ano = []
                page.goto(link)
    with page.expect_download() as download_i:
                    try:
                        page.locator('//html//body//div[1]//div[4]//button').click()
                    except:
                        page.close()
                        page.goto(link)
                        page.locator('//html//body//div[1]//div[4]//button').click()
                    page.locator('//html//body//div[1]//div[4]//ul//li[2]//a').click()
                dl = download_i.value   
                workin_dirf = f'{local_save}/infos-({str(ano)[2:]}).html'
                dl.save_as(workin_dirf)
                page.close()
```

Error occurs on `dl.save_as(workin_dirf)`.

I've tried to execute gunicorn3 with sudo but it doesn't find some modules and, when I fixed it, the script started to works on different folder.

Comment: Please fix your code. If you notice most of it is highlighted green, which means everything is being treated as a string literal. It looks like you didn't include the end of the list of strings on the 3rd line. You also have a `with` statement in the wrong place.

Comment: Sorry, i've copied from nano on linux and i didn't even notice this...

Comment: Did you try VanDam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that when you run the script on your server, the user you're using does not have permission to create either the `local_save` directory *or* the path to that directory. On a Unix-like system, `/var` and most of its subdirectories are generally writable only by root. The exception is `/var/tmp`. If you change your `local_save` variable to be

```py
local_save = '/var/tmp/apis/tceprotocolo'
```

and prior to calling your function, call

```py
os.makedirs(local_save)
```

then your function should successfully write output to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the accepted answer, I suggest you learn about the [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module in python. This gives you some functionality to create temp files. One of the main benefits is that you don't have to hardcode the path to the temp directory.